# I can't make shared library in SunOS 5.8

Tags: c++, c, shared, sunos

I'm going to make shared library in SunOS 5.8

OS Version is 5.8 Generic_108528-29 and g++ version is 2.95.3 20010315 (release)

```
[vector(** NONE **):/tmp/test ] uname -a
SunOS vector 5.8 Generic_108528-29 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V440
[vector(** NONE **):/tmp/test ] g++ -v
Reading specs from /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/2.95.3/specs
gcc version 2.95.3 20010315 (release)
```

It's below test code to make shared lib.

libhello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello_person(char* person)
{
    printf("hello, %s\n", person);
}
```

To make a object file, "g++ -fPIC -c libhello.c"

```
[vector(** NONE **):/tmp/test ] g++ -fPIC -c libhello.c
[vector(** NONE **):/tmp/test ] ls -trl
total 32
-rw-rw-r--   1 dev      users         88 May 25 17:11 libhello.c
-rw-rw-r--   1 dev      users       1228 May 25 17:19 libhello.o
```

and then, "g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libhello.so.1 -o libhello.so.1.1 libhello.o"

but, I got a error that is No output written to libhello.so.1.1.

```
[vector(** NONE **):/tmp/test ] g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libhello.so.1 -o libhello.so.1.1 libhello.o
ld: warning: option -o appears more than once, first setting taken
ld: fatal: file libhello.so.1: open failed: No such file or directory
ld: fatal: File processing errors. No output written to libhello.so.1.1
```

What's problem? What should I look for it?

Comment: You're using antique software — both the version of the compiler and the o/s.  You'll need to get the manuals for GCC 2.95.3 (still available online at the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) documentation web site) and read carefully.  You could try running with a `-v` in the linker command line and see why the `-o` option is claimed to appear twice.  My suspicion is that `-shared` doesn't work.  You may need to look at the Solaris manual for `ld` to find out how to build the shared object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment

When I compiled it with "-v option", I dected that "ldscripts" of SunOs is not exist.
-> "/usr/local/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/lib/ldscripts"

So, I copied it in my system. Making shared lib was success.

Comment: Well done for resolving it.  I could not have told you about that.